# Custom touch area on tableview cell with checkbox iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, uitableview

I've added a checkbox to a table view cell which is a custom button with two images. Clicking this works fine as I can check and uncheck.

The problem is when you click the rest of the row it still selects the checkbox/button. If I comment out didSelectRowAtIndexPath it doesn't happen so I'm wondering how to get around this happening?

A solution I'd be happy with is to allow only selection of the Accessory Disclosure Indicator but there doesn't seem to be a way of doing this.

Sorry if this is a really badly asked question, I'm very tired! Let me know if you need code.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

WedAppDelegate *delegate = (WedAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

PlanTaskShowViewController *planTaskShowViewController = [[PlanTaskShowViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PlanTaskShowViewController" bundle:nil];

[delegate.navController pushViewController:planTaskShowViewControlleranimated:YES];

[planTaskShowViewController release];
}
```

Comment: yes, seeing your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method could help to answer you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put an button on the front instead of an image and do the selecting thing only when button is clicked (change the image of the button).

OR

put an on click event listener / gesture recognizer on your image

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap];
[singleFingerDTap release];
```

//EDIT:

If you use `highlightedImage` for your `UIImageView` or `UIButton` it will be highlighted when selecting the `UITableViewCell`. It's a really nice feature, but sometimes it's only confusing ;)

Comment: The checkbox is currently a button. I'm not having a problem with the checkbox selection it's more to do with the rest of the row triggering the checkbox. Thanks for your help!

Comment: are you using normal and highlighted image? because images are highlighted if you select the cell, instead set the images programmatically

Comment: That sounds like it could be it. Just having a look now. Cheers

Comment: That did it! Do you want to edit your answer or something so I can tick it? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Check this :

UITapGestureRecognizer *singleFingerDTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(changeImage:)];
[imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleFingerDTap];
[singleFingerDTap release];